# Chinese idiom to describe a long line

Tags: idioms

What is the idiom to describe a really long line of people (waiting in line to buy tickets, for example)? I know one of the words is 龙. I tried googling it, but couldn't find it.

Comment: Please add some context. 'Long line' is ambiguous.

Comment: Is there an English idiom?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The chengyu with 龙 could be [大排长龙](http://www.iciba.com/%E5%A4%A7%E6%8E%92%E9%95%BF%E9%BE%99).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the idiom should be 大排长龙。 “a really long line of people waiting in line to buy tickets” could be translated as "等着买票的人大排长龙"。 if you want to say it in plain words: 等着买票的人排了好长的队。